# Convert Windows-1252 hex value to Unicode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

Let's say I have a string containing Windows-1252 hex value for a character, I would like to make that appropriate Unicode character:

```
const asciiHex = '85' //represents hellip
parseInt(asciiHex, 16) //I get 133 as expected
```

I can't do `String.fromCharCode` now as this takes Unicode codes, rather than ASCII (in unicode hellip is 8230 (decimal)). Is anyone aware of any simple conversion?

*btw I am doing this in node 6*

Comment: 133 isn't an ascii value.

Comment: indeed, forgot to say it's extended code in ISO 8859-1

Comment: Well no, it's Windows-1252, as the answer below mentions. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't mention the input encoding: in which character encoding is `\x85` mapped to the horizontal ellipsis? Turns out that's Windows-1252, which Node.js doesn't "speak" out of the box.

A module that can encode/decode it is [`windows-1252`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-1252).

To convert your hex code to a UTF-8 encoded string:

```
const windows1252 = require('windows-1252');

let asciiHex = '85';
let utf8text = windows1252.decode( Buffer.from(asciiHex, 'hex').toString('binary') );

console.log( utf8text ); // outputs: …
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I forgot to mention that it is ISO 8859-1

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk I don't think so, for ISO-8859-1 `\x85` isn't defined (also confirmed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#Computer_representations): _"Note that ISO/IEC 8859 encoding series provides no code point for ellipsis"_).

Comment: tbh I am no good with all the encoding stuff etc, I took my info from http://www.ascii-code.com/. Anyway, your solution works perfectly, thanks :)

Comment: http://czyborra.com/charsets/iso8859.html#ISO-8859-1 `You often see Microsoft Windows users announcing their texts as being in ISO-8859-1 even when in fact they contain funny characters from the CP1252 superset`